# Trying to fix issue with compareTo() method

Tags: java, compareto

I've been working on a project to make a generic binary search tree, and the code is for the most part finished. However, this one part of the code isn't working, and I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
private Node<E> add ( E item, Node<E> root ) {

    if ( root == null ) {
        return new Node<E>(item);
    }
    if ( root.data == item ) {
        return root;
    }
    else if ( root.data.compareTo(item)< 0) {
        root.right =  add ( item, root.right );
    }
    else {
        root.left = add ( item, root.left);
    }
    return root;
}
```

The error occurs on the first "else if" statement, and the error message I get is that "class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (java.lang.String and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')." Outside of the provided code, I have integers and characters being taken as inputs to test that the binary tree works with multiple data types. I know compareTo() can work between characters and integers, it would compare the ascii value of the character against the integer. From there, the only thing I can think of to be causing this issue is the "root.data.compareTo(item)..." If I'm correct, and that is what's causing my issue, how would I be able to compare that specific instance of root.data to the item variable?

I am providing the entire code below, to show the different interactions between classes, objects, and methods.

```
package project4;

import java.util.Iterator;

public class BST<E extends Comparable<E>> extends Object implements Iterable<E>, Cloneable{
    public static void main(String args []){
        BST tree = new BST();
        tree.add("g");
        tree.add(5);
        tree.add(6);
        tree.add(2);
        tree.add(4);
        tree.add("h");
        System.out.println(tree.toStringTreeFormat() );
    }

// actual class definition

    private Node<E>  root;
    private E[] elements;
    
    public BST() {
        root = null;
    }
   /* 
    BST(E[] collection){
        if(collection == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can not provide a null argument");
        }
        else {
            
        }
    }
    */
    // add function
    /*
        public boolean add( int val ) {
            if (root == null ) {
                Node n = new Node (val) ;
                root = n;
                return true;
            }

            return add (val, root);

        }

        private boolean add (int val, Node n ) {

            //found duplicate
            if ( val == n.data) return false;


            if ( val < n.data ) { // go left
                if ( n.left == null ) {//attach it right here
                    Node current = new Node (val);
                    n.left = current;
                    return true;
                }
                else { // recurse to its left subtree
                    return add(val, n.left) ;
                }
            }
            else { // go right
                if ( n.right == null ) {//attach it right here
                    Node current = new Node (val);
                    n.right = current;
                    return true;
                }
                else { // recurse to its right subtree
                    return add(val, n.right) ;
                }

            }
        }
    */

    public boolean add ( E e ) {
        int oldSize = size();
        root  =  add( e, root );
        if (oldSize == size())
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    private Node<E> add ( E item, Node<E> root ) {

        if ( root == null ) {
            return new Node<E>(item);
        }
        if ( root.data == item ) {
            return root;
        }
        else if ( root.data.compareTo(item)< 0) {
            root.right =  add ( item, root.right );
        }
        else {
            root.left = add ( item, root.left);
        }
        return root;
    }

    // remove function



    private boolean found ;

    public boolean remove(E val)
    {
        found = false;
        root = recRemove(val, root);
        return found;
    }

    private Node<E> recRemove(E target, Node<E>  node)
    {
        if (node == null)
            found = false;
        else if (target.compareTo(node.data) < 0)
            node.left = recRemove(target, node.left);
        else if (target.compareTo(node.data) > 0)
            node.right = recRemove(target, node.right );
        else {
            node = removeNode(node);
            found = true;
        }
        return node;
    }

    private Node<E> removeNode(Node<E> node)
    {
        E data;

        if (node.left == null)
            return node.right ;
        else if (node.right  == null)
            return node.left;

        else {
            data = getPredecessor(node.left);
            node.data = data;
            node.left = recRemove(data, node.left);
            return node;
        }
    }

    private E getPredecessor(Node<E> subtree)
    {
        Node<E> temp = subtree;
        while (temp.right  != null)
            temp = temp.right ;
        return temp.data;
    }

    // check if a value is stored in the tree
    public boolean contains (E val ) {
        if (root == null)
            return false;
        Node<E> cur = root;

        do {
            E curVal = cur.data;

            if (val == curVal)  return true;
            if (val.compareTo(curVal) < 0) cur = cur.left;
            else cur = cur.right;

        } while (cur != null) ;

        return false;


    }

    // this should be stored in a data filed to improve performance
    // calculation is done just as an exercise
    public int size ( ) {
        return size(root);
    }
    private int size( Node<E> n ) {
        if (n == null ) return 0;
        return 1 + size(n.left) + size(n.right);
    }

    private static class Node<E>{

        E  data;
        Node<E>  left ;
        Node<E>  right ;

        Node( E data ) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        Node(E data, Node<E> l, Node<E> r ) {
            this.data = data;
            left = l;
            right = r;
        }

    }

    private void preOrderPrint(Node<E> tree, int level, StringBuilder output) {
        if (tree != null) {
            String spaces = "\n";
            if (level > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < level - 1; i++)
                    spaces += "   ";
                spaces += "|--";
            }
            output.append(spaces);
            output.append(tree.data);
            preOrderPrint(tree.left, level + 1, output);
            preOrderPrint(tree.right, level + 1, output);
        }
        // uncomment the part below to show "null children" in the output
        
        else {
            String spaces = "\n";
            if (level > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < level - 1; i++)
                    spaces += "   ";
                spaces += "|--";
            }
            output.append(spaces);
            output.append("null");
        }
        
    }


    public String toStringTreeFormat() {

        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

        preOrderPrint(root, 0, s);
        return s.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Hints: 1) using `==` instead of `equals()` or, in this specific case, `compareTo()` to compare reference types; 2) -deleted after question edit-

Comment: @Mr.Moffia You shouldn't use raw type of your `BST` class, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Comment: @user85421 So, for every time I have E as a variable type in the parameters of a method, I want to have it instead be E extends Comparable? 
For example, instead of, say, "public boolean add(E e)," I'd want "public boolean add(E extends Comparable e)?"

Comment: I deleted that part since the code is already doing as suggested - I just could not see it because it was not posted when I was writing the comment :-|  || Are different types being added (like `String` and `int`?

Comment: @user85421 All good! if anything, I apologize for that, I don't use stack overflow all too much, so I'm still getting used to exactly what I should have in a question from the beginning

Comment: "*I know compareTo() can work between characters and integers*" <-- have you tested that? `char` and `int` can be compared, but both are primitives and do not have methods (e.g. `compareTo()`)

Comment: @Progman To be honest, that's something I'm meaning to make it's own question lol, I've tried to use BST<E> rather than just BST() in the main method, but then I get an error about not being able to make a static reference to a non static type E.

Comment: @user85421 I've used compareTo() before between an integer and character before, but that was when they were both stored in generic variables. I guess I should have been more careful with how I worded that, my bad!

Comment: `Comparable i = 65; Comparable s = "A"; i.compareTo(s)` -> "*ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer*"  [screesnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UE6wF.png)

Comment: @user85421 hm, alright. If that's the case, then, how would I fix the issue I'm experiencing? I just need to compare the ascii value of any characters taken as an input, without replacing the characters with the ascii value. The binary tree should be able to have characters and integers in it.

Comment: first you must decide how to compare strings with integer, or better, how to compare "*with multiple data types*"

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use [`Comparable<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) to compare `Integer` and `String` instances, because `Integer` cannot be cast to a `String` or vice versa. This means that a `Comparable<Integer>` instance cannot be called with `compareTo("abc")`. The fact that you are using your `BST<E>` class as a "raw type" (see [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)) without using the generic type makes it even more complicated because it *looks like* it is working (because your `add()` method allows any type), but it doesn't (as you see by the exception).

If you want to add `String` and `Integer` instances to your `BST` class, you have to drop the generic type `E` and its restriction to `extends Comparable<E>` or change it to just `Object`. That way you can add any object to your `BST` class. But this also means that you have to provide your own compare method, which must compare two instances and return an ordering for them, specially when they have different types.

This is what the [`Comparator<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface is specifying. It is used to compare two instances with the [`compare(T, T)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) method. As an example, the [`TreeSet<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) class can work with an `Comparator<T>` instance in case the objects cannot be sorted by themself.

You can use the `TreeSet` approach and say "I want to use a BST and use **that** comparator to compare the objects". This means that you have to implement the `Comparator<Object>` interface in a new class, which compares `Integer` and `String` objects for you. You have to use the generic type `Object` since that is the common base class for `Integer` and `String`. The new class body will look like this:

```
public class ASCIIComparator implements Comparator<Object> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        
    }
}
```

The tricky part is obviously the `compare()` method since you have to check different situations like comparing two strings, two integers or one string and one integer. Also you have to check that no other types are used and throw an exception (which must be documented somewhere that it does throw an exception). That also means that you can't get around to convert your strings and integers to ASCII values, which you then can compare. But you can do *that* inside this `compare()` method, without affecting what you store in your `BST` class.

When you have such `ASCIIComparator` class, you can rewrite your `BST` class to work with any `Comparator<T>` instance. The class body should be rewritten like this:

```
public class BST<E> implements Iterable<E>, Cloneable {
    private final Comparator<E> comparator;

    public BST(Comparator<E> comparator) {
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }

    // [...]
}
```

Then inside your `add()` method, you use the `this.comparator` instance to compare two instances and decide what to do like this:

```
// [...]
int order = this.comparator.compare(root.data, item);
if (order < 0) {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
// [...]
```

The generic type `E` ensures, that the comparator given in the constructor call must also be of type `Comparator<E>`, so it must "fit" for the `BST` class. With that you can create a `BST` class with the `ASCIIComparator` like this:

```
    BST<Object> tree = new BST<Object>(new ASCIIComparator());
    tree.add("g"); // String is an Object
    tree.add(5);   // Integer is an Object (autoboxed)
    tree.add(6);
    tree.add(2);
    tree.add(4);
    tree.add("h");
    System.out.println(tree.toStringTreeFormat() );
```

Since the `ASCIIComparator` class is implementing the `Comparator<Object>` interface, your `BST` class have to use the generic type `Object` as well.